# Mapping natively not working in my phone android

Tags: android, google-maps, codenameone

I'm developing a simple app with codename one on netbeans, and everything goes ok on the simulator, but the maps doesn't show at all in my phone android...
I followed all the instructions I found about this topic (the build hints are ok, the API KEY is ok, etc), but it still doesn't work...
Does anyone can tell me if I'm missing something?

```
    //add the map to the form 
    cnt = new MapContainer(HTML_API_KEY);
    formTUTTO.addComponent(cnt);
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wQlm.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Filtering with the word "google" these are the log lines that appear while I'm launching the app from my mobile:

12-15 20:09:09.749: W/BroadcastQueue(839): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } from com.android.launcher3 (pid=2776, uid=10019) requires com.google.android.launcher.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to receiver com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.icingsync.ApplicationLaunchReceiver

12-15 20:09:09.749: W/BroadcastQueue(839): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } from com.android.launcher3 (pid=2776, uid=10019) requires com.google.android.launcher.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to receiver com.google.android.gms/.icing.proxy.ApplicationLauncherReceiver

12-15 20:09:09.750: W/BroadcastQueue(839): Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$GmsExternalReceiver requires com.android.launcher3.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.android.launcher3 (uid 10019)

12-15 20:09:11.270: W/System(1983): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000031/n/armeabi

12-15 20:09:11.461: I/Google Maps Android API(1983): Google Play services client version: 9452000

12-15 20:09:11.487: I/Google Maps Android API(1983): Google Play services package version: 11951436

12-15 20:09:12.143: I/Google Maps Android API(1983): Google Play services package version: 11951436

12-15 20:09:14.154: W/DynamiteModule(1983): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.

12-15 20:09:14.155: W/DynamiteModule(1983): Failed to load module via V2: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

12-15 20:09:14.214: I/DynamiteModule(1983): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4

12-15 20:09:14.214: I/DynamiteModule(1983): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4

12-15 20:09:14.255: W/System(1983): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002f/n/armeabi-v7a

12-15 20:09:14.256: W/System(1983): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000002f/n/armeabi

12-15 20:09:14.335: W/ConfigurationChimeraPro(2569): Caller is not authorized to access Uri: content://com.google.android.gms.phenotype/com.google.android.gms.clearcut.public

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to understand this due to the language, it would help if you switch to English for the screenshots as I could give a more definitive answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'll send new screenshots in english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it... It wasn.t a problem of API.
I just added this row in my code:

```
formTUTTO.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

And I added the argument BorderLayout in the following row:

```
formTUTTO.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,cnt);
```

Now everything works fine :)
CiaoCiao, and thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the API key from JavaScript for the native Android integration. You need to activate the [native Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) and native iOS SDK's and use the keys that are given there.

Comment: It seems to me that I've already done what you said, apart for the iOS SDK (I'm not using iOS devices)... Map still not showing on my android cell, even if it seems that requestes have been sended correctly (looking at the last screenshot). Thank's for the answers!!!!

Comment: The Android API in your screenshot seems to be disabled and not a screenshot from the link I provided. Notice you need to set it as a build hint based on the instructions here https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-improved-native-google-maps.html or https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/ Make sure you set the build hint through the build hints UI and don't make mistakes by editing `codenameone_settings.properties` directly which is a common mistake

Comment: Sorry if I bother you, but I'm still missing something... You say "The Android API in your screenshot seems to be disabled and not a screenshot from the link I provided." but I got the API_KEY from that link, and it seems to me that the API is enabled (in the first screenshot it says Google Maps Android API ENABLED, and in the following screenshots it says that 4 requests have been sent, with no error)... I have followed your instructions, and I have set the build hints through the build hints UI. I'm still missing something :(

Comment: OK, the best approach to track these issues is connect the device with a cable and look at the logcat/DDMS output which Google prints out to the console. It would indicate where the issue would be.

Comment: I'm really new to it, but I'm gonna try... I hope that what I'm posting is what you are talking about...

Comment: No you should connect the cable, clear the log completely then launch the app. Just look at what's printed there it will usually have the name of your app next to it but might not. It should probably indicate an error with the key or something similar to that.